# Consulta sql en cadena string, rango de fechas

Tags: c#

Tengo este código el cual carga un *report viewer*:

```
DateTime fechai = (DateTime)dateTime_desde.Value;
DateTime fechaf = (DateTime)dateTime_hasta.Value;

try
{
    ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();
    //Es necesario  cambiar aquí.. exactamente que esto...
    rds.Name = "DataSet1"; //Nombre del dataset que use en el archivo .rdlc 
                           //Y también debemos colocar la consulta que se adapte al nuevo dataset
    String Sql = "SELECT AMEMPL.EM_NUMEMP, AHMOVS.MV_FECHA FROM AMEMPL INNER JOIN AHMOVS ON AMEMPL.EM_NUMEMP = AHMOVS.MV_NUMEMP WHERE AHMOVS.MV_HORAS BETWEEN '" + fechai + "' AND '" + fechaf + "'";

    rds.Value = llenaTabla(Sql);
    reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
    reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    conexion_bd.Close();
}
```

Con la consulta mando el `DataSet` al *report* de esta manera:

```
public DataTable llenaTabla(string commandText)
{
    DataTable TABLA = new DataTable("Tmp");
    try
    {
        int i;
        conexion_bd.Open();
        OleDbCommand CMD = new OleDbCommand(commandText, conexion_bd);
        OleDbDataReader REG = CMD.ExecuteReader();
        for (i = 0; i < REG.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            TABLA.Columns.Add(REG.GetName(i), REG.GetFieldType(i));
        }

        while (REG.Read())
        {
            DataRow ROWS = TABLA.NewRow();
            for (i = 0; i < REG.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                ROWS.SetField(i, REG[i]);
            }
            TABLA.Rows.Add(ROWS);
        }
        REG.Close();
        conexion_bd.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("","" + ex.Message, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        conexion_bd.Close();
    }
    return TABLA;
}
```

Mi problema es que no acepta las fechas, primero me da el error que dice "Los criterios no coinciden" y ahorita no me marca nada pero no carga dentro del rango de fechas. Ya sá que se puede utilizar una consulta parametrizada, pero en este caso es una cadena string.

Espero me puedan orientar sobre qué problema tengo o por qué no me acepta las fechas.

Answer (score 0):

'Cambia la siguiente línea:

```
String Sql = "SELECT AMEMPL.EM_NUMEMP, AHMOVS.MV_FECHA FROM AMEMPL INNER JOIN AHMOVS ON AMEMPL.EM_NUMEMP = AHMOVS.MV_NUMEMP WHERE AHMOVS.MV_HORAS BETWEEN '" + fechai + "' AND '" + fechaf + "'";
```

por:

```
String Sql = string.Format("SELECT AMEMPL.EM_NUMEMP, AHMOVS.MV_FECHA FROM AMEMPL INNER JOIN AHMOVS ON AMEMPL.EM_NUMEMP = AHMOVS.MV_NUMEMP WHERE AHMOVS.MV_HORAS BETWEEN '{0} 00:00.000' AND '{1} 23:59.000' ", fechai.ToString("yyyyMMdd"), fechaf.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: No funciono, pasa lo mismo.. Pero muchas gracias

Comment: En qué número de línea o cuál línea te marca el error?

Comment: De echo no me marca error, se ejecuta pero no me trae resultados. de echo intente lo siguiente

Answer (score 0):

//da2.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT MV_FECHA,MV_DIASEML,MV_HORAS,MV_TLBRBLE,MV_TCUMP,MV_TCDIF,MV_TTRBJDO,MV_SLDODIA,MV_TDHRSAL,MV_PRIENT,MV_ULTSAL,MV_OBSERV FROM AHMOVS WHERE MV_NUMEMP BETWEEN @empini AND @empfin AND MV_FECHA BETWEEN @desde AND @hasta ORDER BY MV_NUMEMP,MV_FECHA", conexion2);
                da2.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empini", tb_ini.Text);
                da2.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empfin", tb_fin.Text);
                da2.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desde", dateTime_desde.Value);
                da2.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hasta", dateTime_hasta.Value.AddDays(1));

De echo intente eso y aqui si funciona, creo que la solucion es parametrizar la fecha

Comment: Pero no se como hacerlo en una cadena string esa de arriba es una consulta como tal con oledb de access

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomiendo que cambies la *firma* de tu método `llenaTabla` para que tome los parámetros que necesite:

```
public DataTable llenaTabla(string commandText, params OleDbParameter[] parámetros)
{                                            // ^ agregas cuantos parámetros requieras
    DataTable TABLA = new DataTable("Tmp");
    try
    {
        int i;
        conexion_bd.Open();
        OleDbCommand CMD = new OleDbCommand(commandText, conexion_bd);

        // Agregas los parámetros a la consulta
        foreach (OleDbParameter p in parámetros)
        {
            CMD.Parameters.Add(p);
        }

        OleDbDataReader REG = CMD.ExecuteReader();
        ...
    }
    return TABLA;
}
```

Para invocarlo con los parámetros de fecha, lo haces así:

```
try
{
    ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();
    rds.Name = "DataSet1";
    String Sql = "SELECT AMEMPL.EM_NUMEMP, AHMOVS.MV_FECHA"
                + " FROM AMEMPL INNER JOIN AHMOVS ON AMEMPL.EM_NUMEMP = AHMOVS.MV_NUMEMP"
               + " WHERE AHMOVS.MV_HORAS BETWEEN ? AND ?";

    rds.Value = llenaTabla(Sql, // Aquí pasas los parámetros que requieras
                           new OleDbParameter("@fechai", fechai),
                           new OleDbParameter("@fechaf", fechaf));
    reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
    reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
}
```

Aquí solo vale la pena remarcar que, en el caso de queries con `OleDb`, los parámetros solo se indican con un `?` por lo que hay que añadir los parámetros en el orden estricto en que deben ser sustituidos, y si esto no funciona, entonces usa los parámetros nombrados (`WHERE AHMOVS.MV_HORAS BETWEEN @fechai AND @fechaf`).